# How to display the total count of the last row by filestatus?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have to display the total count of the last row by filestatus.

**tbl_bankdata**

```
bank_id | b_orderno| b_bankname| lead_id
     1  | 01-01    | 1         |  1
     2  | 01-02    | 2         |  1
     3  | 02-01    | 3         |  2
     4  | 03-01    | 1         |  3
```

**tbl_fileStatus**

```
f_id | f_bankid| f_filestatus
  1  |      1  | 1
  2  |      2  | 1
  3  |      2  | 2
  4  |      1  | 2
  5  |      1  | 3
  6  |      3  | 2 
  7  |      3  | 3
```

I have two tables `tbl_bankdata` and `tbl_fileStatus`. I am sending `bank_id` in the `tbl_fileStatus` as a `f_bank_id`.

Now I have to show the last `f_bankid` count.

For example, I have to fetch the count where f_filestatus=1. so my output will be `0`. Why `0` because `f_bankid 1 and 2` have a `f_filestatus=1` but `f_bankid 1 and 2` have the last row with f_filestatus the `3 and 2`.

If I have to count `f_filestatus=2` then I will get the output `1` and if count `f_filestatus=3` then the output will be `2`. why 2 because `f_bank_id 1` have `f_filestatus 3` and `f_bank_id 3` have `f_filestatus 3`

This is my query

```
select (
    SELECT COUNT(f_id) 
    FROM tbl_fileStatus 
    WHERE f_filestatus=1 and f_id IN (
        SELECT MAX(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus GROUP BY f_bankid
    )
) as tcount
```

Would you help me out with this issue?

After suggested by @forpas

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(DISTINCT f_bankid)
    FROM   tbl_filestatus t
    WHERE  1 = (SELECT f_filestatus
                FROM   tbl_filestatus
                WHERE  f_bankid = t.f_bankid
                ORDER  BY f_id DESC
                LIMIT  1)) AS tcount1,
   (SELECT Count(DISTINCT f_bankid)
    FROM   tbl_filestatus t
    WHERE  2 = (SELECT f_filestatus
                FROM   tbl_filestatus
                WHERE  f_bankid = t.f_bankid
                ORDER  BY f_id DESC
                LIMIT  1)) AS tcount2,
   (SELECT Count(DISTINCT f_bankid)
    FROM   tbl_filestatus t
    WHERE  3 = (SELECT f_filestatus
                FROM   tbl_filestatus
                WHERE  f_bankid = t.f_bankid
                ORDER  BY f_id DESC
                LIMIT  1)) AS tcount3
```

Comment: What output do you expect? What's wrong with your query?

Comment: @JeffUK, f_filestatus=1 then cout 0, f_filestatus=2 count 1 f_filestatus=3 then count 2

Comment: What MySQL version you have? Since MySQL 8 you can use window functions to solve this problem

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev, PHPmyadmin 5.0.4 is installed

Comment: @user9437856 the count of the last row will always be 1...can you add an example expected resultset to your question please?

Comment: @JeffUK, I added an explanation to the question but still let me try to add example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f_bankid) AS tcount
FROM tbl_fileStatus t
WHERE ? = (SELECT f_filestatus FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_bankid = t.f_bankid ORDER BY f_id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Replace `?` with the `f_bankid` you search for.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=510f2d445308228b24124819977280d7).

In MySql 8.0+ you can use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tcount
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT f_bankid, 
         FIRST_VALUE(f_filestatus) OVER (PARTITION BY f_bankid ORDER BY f_id DESC) f_filestatus
  FROM tbl_fileStatus
) t
WHERE f_filestatus = ?
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d84b1d0c270a93ae07d6bc6d86c0bc9a).

If you want results for all `f_filestatus` in 1 row:

```
SELECT
  SUM(f_filestatus = 1) AS tcount1,
  SUM(f_filestatus = 2) AS tcount2,
  SUM(f_filestatus = 3) AS tcount3
FROM (
  SELECT t.f_bankid, t.f_filestatus
  FROM tbl_fileStatus t
  WHERE t.f_id = (SELECT f_id FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_bankid = t.f_bankid ORDER BY f_id DESC LIMIT 1)
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8359d3a37affbc1ba345447b557a4124).
Results:

```
> tcount1 | tcount2 | tcount3
> ------: | ------: | ------:
>       0 |       1 |       2
```

Comment: I can't get this one WHERE ?

Comment: @user9437856 Replace ? with 1 or 2 or 3. Check the demo in my answer.

Comment: I have to set alias name for each f_filestatus because I have to show it on the dashboard. like in my question I set  as tcount for the  f_filestatus=1

Comment: @user9437856 just add `AS tcount`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Give me some time to implement in my code

Comment: I tried your first solution and it's working. In the second solution, I am getting some version issues.

Comment: @user9437856 the 2nd query works only in MySql 8.0+ so probably your version is earlier.

Comment: I added the query in the question. Can you check it once? I have to add more conditions till 8. so is there any other way to reduce the query?

Comment: @user9437856 This is a different requirement. See my 3d query in my edited answer.

Comment: I apologize, for the new requirement. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0, I woud recommend `row_number()`:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from (
    select fs.*,
        row_number() over(partition by f_bank_id order by f_id desc) rn
    from tbl_filestatus fs
) fs
where rn = 1 and filestatus = ?
```

An alternative that works across all versions is a correlated subquery:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from tbl_filestatus fs
where fs.f_id = (
    select max(fs1.f_id)
    from tbl_filestatus fs1
    where fs1.f_bank_id = fs.bank_id and fs1.filestatus = ?
)
```

For performance with the second query, consider an index on `(bank_id, filestatus, fs_id desc)`. With this index, that query may run faster than the first approach using `row_number()`, even in MySQL 8.0.

If you want the count for all `filestatus`es at once:

```
select filestatus, count(*) as cnt
from tbl_filestatus fs
where fs.f_id = (
    select max(fs1.f_id)
    from tbl_filestatus fs1
    where fs1.f_bank_id = fs.bank_id
)
group by filestatus
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next query with one exception - query does not return 0 result but it can be solved on visualisation level:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_fileStatus 
JOIN (
    SELECT f_bankid, MAX(f_filestatus) AS max_f_filestatus
    FROM tbl_fileStatus GROUP BY f_bankid
) AS m ON m.max_f_filestatus = tbl_fileStatus.f_filestatus and
  m.f_bankid = tbl_fileStatus.f_bankid
  WHERE tbl_fileStatus.f_filestatus = 3 -- or 2 or any other value :)
```

[Test SQL here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=cf49d1d6a98f70ecbb8025d4780c5a5f&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)