# How to display the one column the data for 30 days and rest will display for 90 days with same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

A few days ago I ask a question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65466022/how-to-display-the-total-count-of-the-last-row-by-filestatus) and it's solved my issue using below query. I just added `and t.date_of_created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)` to display the data only for 90 days and it's working.

Now my issue is, I have to show   `SUM(f_filestatus = 3) AS tcount3` only for 30 days and rest will display data for 90 days.

Any idea show to do this?

```
SELECT
  SUM(f_filestatus = 1) AS tcount1,
  SUM(f_filestatus = 2) AS tcount2,
  SUM(f_filestatus = 3) AS tcount3
FROM (
  SELECT t.f_bankid, t.f_filestatus
  FROM tbl_fileStatus t
  WHERE t.f_id = (SELECT f_id FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_bankid = t.f_bankid and t.date_of_created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) ORDER BY f_id DESC LIMIT 1)
) t
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Sure, I just want to know is it possible with same query? or do I need to use two different query? last column for 30 days and rest column for 90 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write your current query using window functions:

```
SELECT SUM(f_filestatus = 1) AS tcount1,
       SUM(f_filestatus = 2) AS tcount2,
       SUM(f_filestatus = 3) AS tcount3
FROM (SELECT fs.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f_bank_id ORDER BY date_of_created DESC, f_id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tbl_fileStatus fs
      WHERE fs.date_of_created > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY
     ) fs
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

But the answer to your question is to simply add a new condition:

```
SELECT SUM(f_filestatus = 1) AS tcount1,
       SUM(f_filestatus = 2) AS tcount2,
       SUM(f_filestatus = 3 AND fs.date_of_created > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS tcount3
FROM (SELECT fs.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f_bank_id ORDER BY date_of_created DESC, f_id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tbl_fileStatus fs
      WHERE fs.date_of_created > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY
     ) fs
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

You can use the same idea in older versions:

```
SELECT SUM(f_filestatus = 1) AS tcount1,
       SUM(f_filestatus = 2) AS tcount2,
       SUM(f_filestatus = 3 AND fs.date_of_created > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS tcount3
FROM tbl_fileStatus fs
WHERE fs.f_id = (SELECT fs2.f_id
                 FROM tbl_fileStatus fs2
                 WHERE fs2.bank_id = fs.bank_id AND
                       fs2.date_of_created > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY
                 ORDER BY fs2.f_id DESC
                 LIMIT 1
                )
```

Comment: Apologize, my MySql is not 8.0+ and PARTITION work with 8.0 +

Comment: Sir, Yes, It's working, Can we set the between range date? I mean I have to show the records only for one month and date 01st to 31st. As of now it's displaying the last 30days records. right?

Comment: @user9437856 . . . This answers the question that you asked here ("for 30 days").  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Comment: Sir, Yes, I know, I have to ask new question for new requirement.  I tried SUM(f_filestatus = 3 AND MONTH(fs.date_of_created)= MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())) AS tcount3. Is this correct way ?

Comment: @user9437856 . . . I think that will work as long as you are filtering out data from previous years.

Comment: Yes, I have to show only current month data.